# Getting 'next' and 'previous' when sorted by field that is not unique

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sorting

I'm making a gallery of images. User can sort this gallery by rating:

```
SELECT *
FROM images
WHERE album_id=8
ORDER BY rating DESC, id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

This will result in list of images, that I happily display to user:

```
image_id | rating
--------------------
25       | 10
23       | 10
18       | 9
16       | 9   -- user will click here
15       | 9
89       | 8
67       | 8
60       | 8
5        | 8
101      | 3
```

After that, user clicks on this image:

```
image_id | rating
--------------------
16       | 9
```

Now, I need to compose an **SQL queries, that will figure out what will be the next and previous image in the set** to display the links accordingly, knowing only `image_id` and that set is sorted by `rating DESC, id DESC`.

Task seems trivial, but how do I do this? What is the common approach to this problem?

I've tried something like this:

```
   -- get next image
   SELECT *
   FROM images
   WHERE
       album_id=8
       AND rating <= 9     -- rating of current image
       AND image_id < 16   -- id of current image
   ORDER BY rating DESC, id DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

but this does not work for me in case, when next record has different rating.

Is there a more elegant way to approach this problem, given that user can choose both sorting directions and multiple parameters?

P.S. I'm using Django ORM for this, but an answer in simple SQL is fine.